# How can I install GPU drivers using Intel graphics installer?

Tags: graphic-drivers, graphics

I try to install Intel GPU Drivers using Intel Graphics Installer for Linux, but it only works for Ubuntu 15.04 and higher, but elementary is based on 14.04.

Is there any other way to install these drivers?
I can't find out my GPU model, but it's integrated Intel.

Comment: It seems I added kind of a duplicate: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8489/intel-5500-graphics-performance-on-loki but my question has a link where I provide a answer to your question. The problem is, **the drivers from Intel do not solve the initial problem of poor performance**.

Comment: Check that link again. If you have performance issues my answer there may help you.